# Angular2 cli hangs while creating a new app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a new Angular2 app using

```
ng new myAppName
```

This hangs on the line

```
/ Installing packages for tooling via npm
```

Its been sitting there for about an hour.

The previous time this happend I killed the process and tried re-running

```
ng new xxx
```

That failed because angular cli had some reference to the app name somewhere and  thats whay I had to choose a new app name.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Did you try to `npm remove -g angular-cli` 
then `npm i -g angular-cli` ?

Comment: Try `ng new <app-name> -verbose`. This will give you the details about package downloads that may help you figure out exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I was trying to install Angular on an external flash drive which I believe was part of my problem. Siva Sankar's method Yarn worked for me, although I also had to move my Angular app directory to my laptop's HDD.

Answer (score 21):

I was having the same issue. I resolved by using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/). Follow below steps

1. Install yarn through npm using the below command

   npm install yarn --global
2. Create your application using `ng new` but skip installing packages using the below command. You can install them manually using `yarn`

   `ng new project-name --skip-install`
3. `cd project-name`
4. `yarn install` 
   This will install your dependencies super-fast

Comment: I was having the exact same problem and this fixed my issue.

Comment: @Siva Sankar Rajendran I am getting error when  I give yarn install as follows error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@angular%2fplatform-browser: unable to get local issuer certificate".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\\learn\\my-cli-app\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

Comment: this worked for myself after many hours fighting with npm. Note - I did have to run the following to gert around the certificate issue mentioned above: yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g

Comment: Man it was a battle for hours! My battle with this NPM issue will be legendary! But this solution hits it in a minute. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try to **run cmd** as **Administrator**, it will take **4** to **5 minutes**.

Comment: Worked for me. It literally took minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
npm cache clean

If angular cli already installed, run ng new command

ng new xxx

Hope this helps.

Thanks, 
Jasmin

Answer (score 1):

Some people install `angular-cli` using root user (sudo) because on some systems using a regular user will cause a permission error. But his may cause further problems like the one you are facing.

To fix it:

1) Remove your global angular-cli (using sudo):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

2) Follow the instructions on page below to fix npm permissions:

```
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions
```

3) Reinstall angular-cli, this time not using sudo:

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue run

```
ng new myAppName --skip-install
```

then in command line go to the new project folder

```
cd myAppName
```

then run

```
npm install
```

This fixed the problem for me.

The second way is to just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> at the time it hangs on

```
 Installing packages for tooling via npm
```

and the go to the project folder and run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just waited a bit longer and finally it create the project. So, be patient!

Comment: How long did yours install?

Comment: At most 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the last version of node.js because according to angular 2 site :

> If Node.js and npm aren't already on your machine, install them. Our
>   examples require node v5.x.x or higher and npm 3.x.x or higher. To
>   check which version you are using, run node -v and npm -v in a
>   terminal window.

[Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#prereq)

Answer (score 0):

1) Uninstall the angular-cli

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

2) Try cache clean

```
npm cache clean
```

3) Install angular-cli

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting an error, delete the node_modules and require then anew by `npm install`. In my case, after that I saw an actual error message  which was:

`Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 39:16 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in /..../app/app.module.ts`, after defining a factory for a provider in my module.

Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem, which was resulted by a VERY slow net connection

"Installing packages for tooling via npm."  downloads and installs the tool so it migth take few minutes

1. If you are installing on Linux you need to install angular-cli without root permissions
   https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions
2. You probably need to delete the new project directory created, on linux run "rm -rf myprojectname" where myprojectname stands for the name of your project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I waited a little longer and it said `Installed packages for tooling via npm.`

Checkout this issue on github for the same: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3032

Running it with `--skip-install` or `--skip-npm` worked for some.

```
ng new myAppName --skip-install
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this is because the npm tries to install the dependencies.

You can skip to install the dependencies right now. And then install them later by using following command :

```
ng new myAppName --skip--install
```

and then go to myAppName and run npm install

```
cd myAppName
npm install
```

After all the dependencies are installed. Now you can start you application using :

```
npm start
```

For more info please read the following thread :
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3032

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue while setting up Angular on windows 10. It was getting stuck while installing dependencies after all the CREATE's were done for the first application. For me this was happening because I was running the command from my laptop sitting at home and was connected to company VPN. When I disconnected from VPN and commented out the proxy settings in .npmrc ( it was needed for npm to work via corporate network ) the issue got resolved.